# Undefined reference to pthread for Gtest

Tags: c++, googletest

I have been scratching my head since yesterday trying to make gtest work but I just can't fix it after reading the links below.

[undefined reference to `pthread_key_create' (linker error)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21116622/undefined-reference-to-pthread-key-create-linker-error)

[error during making GTest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10315016/error-during-making-gtest)

The compilation error displayed is this:

```
g++ main.o tests.o var.o -L ../gmock/lib/.libs -L ../gmock/gtest/lib/.libs 
-lgtest -lgmock -lpthread -o test 
../gmock/gtest/lib/.libs/libgtest.so: undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
../gmock/gtest/lib/.libs/libgtest.so: undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
../gmock/gtest/lib/.libs/libgtest.so: undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
../gmock/gtest/lib/.libs/libgtest.so: undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [test] Error 1
```

My Makefile is:

```
CXXFLAGS=-I ../gmock/include -I ../gmock/gtest/include
test:main.o tests.o var.o 
    g++ $^ -L ../gmock/lib/.libs -L ../gmock/gtest/lib/.libs -lgtest -lgmock -lpthread -o $@
```

I am still in the process of learning Linux, compiling and linking source files.

Comment: Have you tried using `-pthread` as indicated in your first linked question?

Comment: +2 the above or try moving -lphtread to the beginning of the link flags

Comment: I tried `CXXFLAGS=-I ../gmock/include -I ../gmock/gtest/include
test:main.o tests.o var.o 
 g++ $^ -L ../gmock/lib/.libs -L ../gmock/gtest/lib/.libs -lgtest -lgmock -pthread -o $@ `

but still didn't work, same as through moving it to the beginning of the link flags

Answer (score 1):

The Error is about linking error on pthread.
You have to make the pthread flag to `-pthread` and the follow CXX should do the trick.

```
LDLIBS =  -L../gmock/lib/.libs -L../gmock/gtest/lib/.libs -lgtest -lgmock 
test:main.o tests.o var.o
    g++ -isystem $(LDLIBS) -pthread  $^ -o $@
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37382804/project-makefile-problems-with-google-test) link have a good Makefile which addresses all your problems and it follows general standards on creating a Makefile